# Kubernetes : How to limit traffic to only two types of pods labeled 'A' and 'B' using a NetworkPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have two types of pods A and B

Pod Type **A**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: A
  labels:
    environment: production
spec:
...
```

Pod Type **B**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: B
  labels:
    environment: production
spec:
...
```

And a NetworkPolicy (still don't know the proper way to use podselection)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
spec:
  podSelector: {"A", "B"}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

**Question :** How do I define a single `NetworkPolicy` to limit traffic to only A & B pods (both ingress & egress) using a '`NetworkPolicy`' in Kubernetes

*References used : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/*

Comment: If you want to use `name` then you probably want to use `matchExpressions` instead

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'matchExpression'. What section of the manifest would this be in?

Comment: Same section (spec.podSelector.matchExpressions), here's [an example in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#set-references-in-api-objects)

Comment: You can see it if you look at the API reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#labelselector-v1-meta (this is dependent on your k8s version, this link is for v1.20)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pod selectors do not have `or` condition on `labels`. The solution will be to create a common label in both pods - `a` and `b` and use pod selector on that common label.

In your question, you should use `environment: production` as a label to select correct pods. Pod selector works on `labels` and not the `name` of the pod.

Comment: Please create a new label if you have other pods that will match `environment: production` and only want pods x, y, and z to match otherwise you will match all pods with that label